# File-system browser for JavaFX

Tags: java, file-management

I am looking for an implementation of a control in modern [JavaFX (OpenJFX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) version 14 or later to display the contents of a folder from the file system of the host computer.

I have learned how to let the user drag-and-drop a folder from the host computer's [file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) (such as the Finder in macOS). And I have seen the [*DirectoryChooser*](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/directorychooser.html) control for letting the user choose a folder.

After the user has specified a folder, I want to display some kind of hierarchy/tree or [Miller’s Columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) widget that lets the user navigate through the files in the chosen folder. This widget should navigate through nested folders as well. As the user selects a file in the widget, my app will react by doing something with that file such as displaying relevant information.

I found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65zM5rNUIHY) showing how to roll-your-own. I wonder if there might already be a ready-made widget for this purpose.